# Notation (Complex Analysis) function

Tags: complex-analysis, notation

Does this notation
$${\Large \Im f(z)}$$
mean the imaginary part of a complex function?

Comment: If that's what I meant, I would write $\Im(f(z))$ instead. What you gain in ink by omitting the outer parentheses you more than lose in clarity. Did you see this notation in a book, journal or blog?

Answer (score 1):

It is the imaginary part of whatever the function's value is at $z$.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

Where $z$ is the complex variable:
$$z=x+iy$$
and $f$ is a complex function of this variable (with real and imaginary components):
$$f(z) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$

The real component of the function is $u$:
$$\Re\big(f(z)\big) = u(x,y)$$
whereas the imaginary component is $v$:
$$\Im\big(f(z)\big) = v(x,y)$$